How to efficiently multiply all non-diagonal elements by a constant in a pandas DataFrame?
I have a square cost matrix stored as a pandas DataFrame. Rows and columns represent positions [i, j], and I want to multiply all off-diagonal elements (where i != j) by a constant c, without using any for loops for performance reasons.
Is there an efficient way to achieve this in pandas or do I have to switch to numpy and then back to pandas to perform this task?
Example
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
cost_matrix = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

# Constant
c = 4

# Desired output
#    1  8  12
#    16 5  24
#    28 16  9


All the answers using values are 'switching' to numpy.  The cost of that can depend on how the frame was constructed.  If made from a 2d array, values may be that array (or at least a view).  But if the frame is stored as a set of column Series there will be a conversion cost.

That's a very valid point. Actually, if the DataFrame was not constructed from an array, the .values approach won't work. Workaround: cost_matrix = cost_matrix.copy().

What do you mean by "efficient" exactly? Just not using loops?

Well kind of self-explanatory. I was searching for fast solutions that scale well with minimal effort in implementation.

Build a boolean mask with numpy.identity and update the underlying array in place:
cost_matrix.values[np.identity(n=len(cost_matrix))==0] *= c

output:
    0   1   2
0   1   8  12
1  16   5  24
2  28  32   9

Intermediate:
np.identity(n=len(cost_matrix))==0

array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])

NB. for .values to be a view of the underlying array, the DataFrame must have been constructed from an homogeneous block. If not, it should be converted to one using cost_matrix = cost_matrix.copy().
Alternative
@PaulS suggested to modify all the values and restore the diagonal. I would use:
d = np.diag(cost_matrix)
cost_matrix *= c
np.fill_diagonal(cost_matrix.values, d)

Timings
The mask approach seems to be faster on small/medium size inputs, and the diagonal restoration faster on large inputs. (My previous timings were performed online and I don't reproduce the results with perfplot).
NB. the timings below were computed with c=1 or c=-1 to avoid increasing the values exponentially during the timing.


I know I shouldn't use comments for that, but I love this comparison! Thanks for doing a benchmark :D

You can create a mask for all diagonal elements (i!=j), apply the mask, and then multiply off-diagonal elements:
import pandas as pd

cost_matrix = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

c = 4

# Create a mask where i != j and convert mask to a DataFrame with the same index and columns
mask = cost_matrix.index.values[:, None] != cost_matrix.columns.values
mask_df = pd.DataFrame(mask, index=cost_matrix.index, columns=cost_matrix.columns)

cost_matrix[mask_df] *= c

print(cost_matrix)

This will output
 1   8  12
16   5  24
28  32   9

Note: I think you made a typo in your desired output. Bottom middle should be 32 and not 16
This approach does not affect the original DataFrame (not in-place). Whether values returns a copy or a view can depend on the data types and the version of pandas. However, for homogeneous data types (like integers or floats), it generally returns a view, so modifying it will affect the DataFrame.

Another possible solution, which is based in numpy and whose steps are:

b is assigned the values from cost_matrix.

Element-wise multiplication of b by the scalar c.

In-place replacement of the diagonal elements of a with the original diagonal values from b (using np.diagonal and np.fill_diagonal).


b = cost_matrix.values
a = b * c 
np.fill_diagonal(a, b.diagonal())


Or, avoiding the intermediate storing as @mozway suggests below in a comment:
d = np.diag(cost_matrix)
cost_matrix *= c
np.fill_diagonal(cost_matrix.values, d)


Output:
array([[ 1,  8, 12],
       [16,  5, 24],
       [28, 32,  9]])


I had this in mind and would have used: d = np.diag(cost_matrix)  ; cost_matrix *= c ; np.fill_diagonal(cost_matrix.values, d). This avoids storing a square intermediate. This is 50% slower than my approach for a 200x200 matrix, but a few times faster for 1000x1000.

Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my solution! You are right, and I have added your suggestion to my answer.

cost_matrix * c ** (reduce(not_equal, np.indices(cost_matrix.shape)))

or
cost_matrix * c ** (1-np.identity(len(cost_matrix)).astype(bool))

gives
    0   1   2
0   1   8  12
1  16   5  24
2  28  32   9


Explanation for 1st approach

np.indices(cost_matrix.shape) gives row and column index matrices

array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])


reduce(not_equal,np.indices(cost_matrix.shape)) collapses the above 3-dimensional array by reduce, where not_equal checks the element-wise equality between row and column indices

array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])


The above boolean matrix plays as the exponent of c, to generate a scaling matrix via c ** (reduce(not_equal, np.indices(cost_matrix.shape)))

array([[1, 4, 4],
       [4, 1, 4],
       [4, 4, 1]], dtype=int32)


The exponentiation to get c or 1 is smart (but not very efficient). You might want to give more details for the first approach ;)

@mozway thanks for your comment! Yes, I would say that exponentiation is an expensive operation. It was just for fun and not efficient, definitely. I added more details for the first approach.
